# Spark AR can you check for both eyes opened or closed?

Tags: facebook, instagram, spark-ar-studio

not sure if it's possible, I've been looking around but I haven't yielded any fruitful results, from what I understand on SparkAR studio, there is only Left Eye and Right Eye Closed. Is there something I'm missing, I can't seem to find both eyes open and both eyes closed.

When I try to create a patch for both left and right eye, I can't combine them into one switch.

This is what I currently have in the patch editor:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INs82.png)

Appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "Blink" interaction might be the simplest solution. You can find it under **Your-Face-Tracker-Info-Panel > Interactions > Blink**.

If that doesn't do the trick, an "And" patch can be used to trigger pulses when both the left and right eyes are closed.

Illustrations of each approach attached.

[Blink Interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk0fA.png)

[Using The "And" Patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyrR8.png)